# Are there any known inverse hash lookups for the zero string?

Tags: hash, rainbow-table

Just wondering, are there any known inverse hashes / hash lookups in common hashes (md5, sha1, sha2, etc.) for the zero string hash value? (i.e. bytes 0x00 00 00 00 00 ...)

Or more specifically, for a 128bit hash (like MD5 or SHA1):

```
HASH(x) = 0x00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Obviously it would take reverse hash lookup, or a rainbow table...

Comment: I think I have read something about MD2 or MD4 having this: Someone did create a message which leads to an output with all bits having the value 0. I have nothing to back up this statement, through.

Comment: This would be a first-preimage attack; I'm quite positive that we do not know a numerical answer for either MD5 or SHA-1, and I'm not aware of one for MD2 or MD4 (although there are theoretical preimage attacks on these hashes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2-pass Snefru hash of the one-block message

```
79F6A75E 0397C368 F60C88DE 3133A55E 6D00251C 8ED3567B
CA49F82B A32E5DC4 8F86E479 DD3FF4D6 14DD88C1 A2322E00
```

is all zeros[[1]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-71039-4_28).

However, *no* other major hash function (and it's debatable whether 2-pass Snefru counts as major) with advertised collision and preimage resistance has *ever* had its preimage resistance broken[[2]](https://z.cash/technology/history-of-hash-function-attacks/) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://z.cash/technology/history-of-hash-function-attacks/)), not even MD5[[3]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50429).  If anyone found a preimage of zero under MD5, SHA-1, SHA-2, SHA-3, BLAKE2, *etc.*, it would be quite astonishing.