# Could we break MD5 entirely in the future?

Tags: hash, md5, preimage-resistance

Even of today MD5 is (sadly) still heavily used in some applications. Even big tools like ApacheMD5. But even today there are more then enough MD5 hashes which are still not cracked.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Preimage_vulnerability), the strongest attack at time of writing this seems to be a preimage attack against MD5 which was published in April 2009, was published that breaks MD5's preimage resistance. This attack is **only theoretical**, with a computational complexity of $2^{123.4}$ for full preimage.

But in the future with Quantum computers, could we get all known plaintext for MD5 (or make them collide)? And would anyone who has a quantum computer even take the effort to do so ?

Comment: They're not cracked because nobody's bothered to crack them. Having a complete lookup table of all hashes isn't going to affect people using apache-md5 passwords: they're already screwed for different reasons.

Comment: *Even of today MD5 is (sadly) still heavyly used in some applications*, I wouldn't say that. MD5 is perfectly fine when used in non security related things, like i.e. rsync protocol. Not the best solution thought.

Comment: MD5 is fine for rsync only if you can guarantee that nobody else has control of the chunks of the files you're synchronizing. Do they contain emails someone sent you? *Bzzzt*: Not fine. Do they contain a browser cache from web sites you have visited? *Bzzzt*: Not fine. Do they contain Git repositories you've cloned from someone? *Bzzzt*: Not fine. For general-purpose tools like rsync one stands on very shaky ground when one asserts it's OK—it's not security-related.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: rsync only uses MD5 (MD4 before version 3) as a checksum to improve the quick check based on filesize and last modification time. It is not expected to be resistant to a malicious actor modifying the target files so that the correct ones are not synced (it's a cool attack to take into account by anyone designing a backup system, though).

Comment: Yes, collision attacks have always been followed by successful preimage attacks.

Comment: However, a situation where making someone's rsync intentionally fail is to anyone's benefit is in the end security related - defeating a backup system set up for traceability, plain vandalism, hiding changes when someone checks for changes/tampering via a "dry" rsync... all sound like security breaches.

Comment: @Navin: [citation needed]  With the [notable exception of Snefru](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-71039-4_28), to my knowledge, no serious cryptographic primitive advertised as preimage-resistant has [_ever_ had its preimage resistance broken](https://z.cash/technology/history-of-hash-function-attacks.html).

Comment: MD5 is still non-ideal for non-security related things. Blake2b could easily be used as a quicker drop in replacement for MD5 for PRNG and security purposes.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage  MD2? An [attack](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/089.pdf) was discovered with the equivalent of $2^{73}$ MD2 compressions.

Comment: @forest The _time_ is advertised as $2^{73}$ MD2 compressions, but it requires _space_ for $2^{73}$ message blocks, which far exceeds the cost of the [best generic attacks](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#bruteforce).  Even $2^{55}$ MD2 circuits on a die working independently in parallel, without rainbow tables to optimize a multi-target attack, would be at least as fast—even if communication latency were zero, which is not plausible for a $2^{73}$-block RAM—and undoubtedly much cheaper.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you [follow the reference](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-01001-9_8) for the alleged preimage attack on MD5, you will see that although the time cost is $2^{123.4}$ steps, the memory cost is $2^{45} \times 11$ words of memory, which has a far higher area*time cost than a smart attacker would use—a smart attacker would fit 32 CPU cores or MD5 circuits in parallel into much less die area and get an answer faster, in $2^{123}$ time.  So that attack gives no reason to treat MD5's preimage resistance as below its advertised level.

But the advertised level—the best preimage resistance that can be provided by a 128-bit hash—is not very high.  A smart attacker will do even better: a smart attacker will attack *many targets at once* with a [parallel brute force machine](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#bruteforce) using [rainbow tables](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-540-45146-4_36), and find *one* preimage among $n$ target hashes on a machine parallelized $n^2$ ways with probability $p$ at the area*time cost of about $2^{128}p/n$ evaluations of MD5—much cheaper than the cost of about $2^{128}p$ for an attack on a single target, and in the *time* for $2^{128}p/n^3$ sequential evaluations of the MD5.  This is not an attack on MD5 in particular; this is a generic attack on *any* 128-bit hash.  Could this happen in practice?  It's [within the realm of human feasibility](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/58669/49826), even for a preimage that is not an easily guessable passphrase.

With an array of $k$ quantum computers large enough to run [Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover's_algorithm), you could find a single MD5 preimage with probability $p$ in [about $2^{64}\sqrt{p/k}$ time](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9711070).  Whether this will ever be *cheaper* than the standard generic *classical* parallel brute force attack depends on how cheaply quantum computers capable of running Grover can be built and powered—at the moment, they do not exist at all.  (Studying the quantum *multi-target* story is left as an exercise for the reader.)

That doesn't necessarily mean you would find the original input strings—unless you know something about the distribution of the original input strings and restrict your search to that, you might find gibberish that happens to have the same hash as the original input strings.  (In fact, merely knowing an MD5 hash—a 128-bit string—doesn't mean there ever *was* an ‘original input string’.  Here's an example: 914c24484128dfe05c3060632ee16e3f.  Maybe you can find a preimage for that, but I just pulled it out of /dev/urandom.)  So it would mostly be useful mainly for either (a) filling in very short unknown high-entropy details of large documents the rest of which you know, or (b) inventing substitute strings that will have the same hash and that are useful only in active attacks on systems still using MD5 as a proxy for identity.

As for computing *collisions*—finding pairs of messages $m_0 \ne m_1$ with $\operatorname{MD5}(m_0) = \operatorname{MD5}(m_1)$, with no control over what the common hash value might come out to be—you don't need a quantum computer to do that.  It's practically a [parlor trick](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/170) at this point, costing under a million MD5 computations to make fresh ones, to say nothing of extending existing collisions into longer ones which costs no computation at all.

Comment: With an array of $k$ quantum computers...  you could find a single MD5 preimage in about $2^{64}/k$ time; is that true?  I've looked for parallel versions of Grover's, and the best I could find is $2^{64}/\sqrt{k}$ time.  Do you have a reference for an efficient parallelized version?

Comment: Nope!  I misquoted the paper I cited.  Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the reference; I had thought that was the case, now I have proof...

Comment: When it comes to breaking a hash algorithm, I wouldn't think that finding the original input is the goal. If, for example, a site is distributing an executable binary and publishes the size and an MD5 hash of the file, the attacker's goal wouldn't be to find the original input, but would rather be to create a malicious file of the same size that produces the same hash that they could trick users into downloading and executing.

Comment: @martin: That is certainly one application!  The OP's question seemed to be about recovering what the original plaintexts were, so I focused on that goal.  What you describe is similar to (a), except instead of learning what the original input was, we don't care and just fill it with garbage to match a target hash, like a Bitcoin block.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: There is a way cooler example hash: da5c61e1edc0f18337e46418e48c1290. This hash is actually the md5 hash of 2 different programs, so finding an input which generates this hash means finding one of the possible two inputs. Copied from here: http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

Comment: @Hannebambel Technically, I assume that's "_finding one of the **at least** two possible inputs_"? That two _known_ inputs generate the same hash presumably doesn't preclude a third doing the same.

Comment: @TripeHound: The addition "at least" is a good one. As for a third input generating the same output I am not sure it is safe to say so. This depends on how md5 really works. The only thing I am sure about is that after 2^128+1 inputs there will be at least one duplicate output, after 2^256+1 there will be at least one output 3 times and so on. The inverse statement that any output will occur multiple times given infinitely many inputs is not necessarily true. It is only guaranteed that at least one output will occur infinitely many times given infinitely many inputs.